# Factor fraction, where variable occurring in both, numerator and denominator, only appears once

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, factorization

I have an expression like $$\frac{1+a^2+2 a \cos\left(p\right)}{\left(1+b^2\right)z-1-a^2-2 \left(a+b z\right)\cos\left(p\right)}\text{.}\tag{1}$$

Is there a combination of Mathematica functions to factor it in such a way that fraction (1) only has one $\cos\left(p\right)$? For instance, this would make symbolic integration much easier.

Manipulating (1) manually, one gets $$\frac{-a}{a+b z}\left(1+z\left(-1-\frac{b}{a}-a b-b^2\right)\frac{1}{\left(1+b^2\right) z-1-a^2-2 \left(a+b z\right)\cos\left(p\right)}\right)\tag{2}$$

Mathematica agrees on that both terms (1) and (2) are equivalent:

```
Simplify[
  (1+a^2+2 a Cos[p])/((1+b^2)z-1-a^2-2(a+b z)Cos[p])
  - 
  (-(a/(a+b z))(1+z(-1-b/a-a b-b^2)*1/(-1-a^2+(1+b^2)z-2(a+b z)Cos[p])))
]
(*0*)
```

As I understand it, `Simplify` manipulates an expression and tries to reduce its complexity, which is given as the "length" of its `TreeForm`. Maybe one can force Mathematica to factor and control the TreeForm if it contains a suitable expression?

btw., Mathematica is not strong at factoring expressions of medium length. Any suggestions or links on how to `factor` those?

Comment: `Collect[expr, Cos[p], Simplify]`?

Comment: `Collect[expr, Cos[p], Simplify]` does not change anything, I still get expression (1).

Comment: Might or might not help, but you can try to tinker with the `ComplexityFunction` option, in such a way as to "penalize" presence of `Sin` and `Cos`.

Comment: This sounds good, I also looked up `ExcludedForms` and `TransformationFunctions`. But the hard part is on how to specify those for a specific problem, where one does not know the solution beforehand. But I'll give it a try, thank you.

Comment: I was playing around with `ComplexityFunction -> 
  2^10*Count[
     FullForm[#] /. {Power[_, -1] -> Sequence[]}, _Cos, {0, 
      Infinity}] + LeafCount[#] &`, but the hard thing is that Mathematica's FullForm is different from what I need. Can one combine `ComplexityFunction` and `Hold` in such a way that eq. (2) is exactly in that form, which can be evaluated by `ComplexityFunction`?
I think this route gets rather messy, because `Factor`, `Expand` etc. will not adhere to a form necessary for this `ComlexityFunction`.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig, Mathematica code '(-(a/(a + b z)) (1 + z (-1 - b/a - a b - b^2)*1/(-1 - a^2 + (1 + b^2) z - 2 (a + b z) Cos[p])))' gives different LaTeX version that is used in you post. Is it important for you?

Comment: Mathematicas representation is not important to me. I just tried to avoid double fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's output form:

```
(-(a/(a+b z))(1+z(-1-b/a-a b-b^2)*1/(-1-a^2+(1+b^2)z-2(a+b z)Cos[p])))
```

It is converted to `LaTex` in `Mathematica` as:
$$-\frac{a \left(\frac{z \left(-a b-\frac{b}{a}-b^2-1\right)}{-a^2-2 \cos (p) (a+b z)+\left(b^2+1\right) z-1}+1\right)}{a+b z}$$

The general form of the expression (with a slight abuse of notation) 
$$\frac{a+b x}{c+d x},$$ 
where $x$ stands for $Cos(p)$.

The conversion such as is needed:
$$\frac{b}{d}+\frac{a-\frac{b c}{d}}{c+d x}$$
Such conversion can be done as follows:

```
expr /. (p_/q_) :> 
  PolynomialQuotient[p, q, x] + PolynomialRemainder[p, q, x]/q
```

Another version closer to the case in OP:
$$\frac{b \left(1+\frac{a d-b c}{b}\frac{1}{c+d x}\right)}{d}$$

To comply with OP's form we need an *ad hoc* **Rule**.

```
exp = (1+a^2+2 a Cos[p])/((1+b^2)z-1-a^2-2(a+b z)Cos[p]);

exp /. (x_ + y_ t_)/(v_ + w_ t_) :> (y/w) (1 + 
Simplify[(x w - y v)/y, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength[ToString[#1]] & )] (1/(v + w t)))
```

Result:
$$-\frac{a \left(1+\frac{z \left(-a b-\frac{b}{a}-b^2-1\right)}{-a^2-2 \cos (p) (a+b z)+\left(b^2\right) z-1}\right)}{a+b z}$$
As input form:

```
-((a*((z*(-(a*b)-b/a-b^2-1))/(-a^2-2*Cos[p]*(a + b*z)+(b^2 + 1)*z-1)+1))/(a+b*z))
```

---

**Addenum**
If we want to make polynomial division applied directly to initial expression:

```
f = PolynomialQuotient[Numerator[#], Denominator[#], Cos[p]] + 
   Simplify@PolynomialRemainder[Numerator[#], Denominator[#], Cos[p]]/
    Denominator[#] &;
f[exp]
```

that gives:

> `-(a/(a + b*z)) + ((a + b + a^2*b + a*b^2)*z)/((a + b*z)*(-1 - a^2 + (1 + b^2)*z - 2*(a + b*z)*Cos[p]))`

In `LaTeX` format:
$$\frac{z \left(a^2 b+a b^2+a+b\right)}{(a+b z) \left(-a^2-2 \cos (p) (a+b z)+\left(b^2+1\right) z-1\right)}-\frac{a}{a+b z}$$

Comment: It was more a generic question on how to come from $\frac{a+b x}{c+d x}$ to $\frac{b}{d}+\frac{a d-b c}{d}\frac{1}{c+d x}$, i.e. on how to modify the ComplexityFunction that my expression is "pushed" in the intended form. So manipulating terms manually seems the way to go. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig, I've made some addition, it might be helpfull.